# Join query sets but keep annotated fields with different values

Tags: django

The problem I'm trying to solve is to perform a search that involves multiple steps of relevance based on the initial query, e.g.:

- Search for "Michael Scott"
- Firstly, we try to match "Michael Scott" directly and save it to `full_name`

  - This will probably return the most relevant objects
- Next, multiple queries will be run to search for each word separately like "Michael" and "Scott" and this will be set to `words`

  - This will return lots of results, most being noise if it's a very common name

In the end, the query sets are joined using `full_name | words` but this ends up mixing the results because of the model's ordering while what I wanted was to keep the everything in `full_name` before what's in `words`.

To try to fix that, I annotated both query sets with a new value and tried to order by it after:

```
full_name = full_name.annotate(relevance=Value(1, IntegerField()))
words = words.annotate(relevance=Value(2, IntegerField()))
return (full_name | words).order_by('relevance')
```

What happens is that everything in `words` is changed to also have `relevance=1` instead of keep the value of `2` I set before, rendering my ordering attempt useless...

I know there are other ways to achieve the ordering I want, like converting the query sets to a `list` or other hacks but is there a way to do this in a manner similar to what I tried?

Thanks!

Comment: Are `full_name` and `words` querysets on the same model?

Comment: @schillingt yes, the operations are on query sets of the same model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to be OR-ing your querysets. It sounds like you want a [union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#union).

```
full_name = full_name.annotate(relevance=Value(1, IntegerField()))
words = words.annotate(relevance=Value(2, IntegerField()))

return full_name.union(words).order_by('relevance')
```

If the querysets are on different models, you'll need to be cautious about which fields are included.